# Python Regex Subgroup Capturing

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse the following string:

```
constructor: function(some, parameters, here) {
```

With the following regex:

```
re.search("(\w*):\s*function\((?:(\w*)(?:,\s)*)*\)", line).groups()
```

And I'm getting:

```
('constructor', '')
```

But I was expecting something more like:

```
('constructor', 'some', 'parameters', 'here')
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you change your pattern to:

```
print re.search(r"(\w*):\s*function\((?:(\w+)(?:,\s)?)*\)", line).groups()
```

You'll get:

```
('constructor', 'here')
```

This is because (from [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group)):

> If a group is contained in a part of the pattern that matched multiple times, the last match is returned.

If you can do this in one step, I don't know how. Your alternative, of course is to do something like:

```
def parse_line(line):
    cons, args = re.search(r'(\w*):\s*function\((.*)\)', line).groups()
    mats = re.findall(r'(\w+)(?:,\s*)?', args)
    return [cons] + mats

print parse_line(line)  # ['constructor', 'some', 'parameters', 'here']
```

Comment: Looks like a good solution, although it will raise an exception on trying to parse something like 'abcd'.

Comment: @DJStroky sure, but wouldn't the code from your question `re.search(...).groups()` do the same thing?

Answer (score 6):

One option is to use more advanced [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) instead of the stock `re`. Among other nice things, it supports `captures`, which, unlike `groups`, save every matching substring:

```
>>> line = "constructor: function(some, parameters, here) {"
>>> import regex
>>> regex.search("(\w*):\s*function\((?:(\w+)(?:,\s)*)*\)", line).captures(2)
['some', 'parameters', 'here']
```

Answer (score 5):

The re module doesn't support repeated captures: the group count is fixed. Possible workarounds include:

1) Capture the parameters as a string and then split it:

```
match = re.search("(\w*):\s*function\(([\w\s,]*)\)", line).groups()
args = [arg.strip() for arg in math[1].split(",")]
```

2) Capture the parameters as a string and then findall it:

```
match = re.search("(\w*):\s*function\(([\w\s,]*)\)", line).groups()
args = re.findall("(\w+)(?:,\s)*", match[1])
```

3) If your input string has already been verified, you can just findall the whole thing:

```
re.findall("(\w+)[:,)]", string)
```

Alternatively, you can use the [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) module and captures(), as suggested by @georg.

Answer (score 0):

You might need two operations here (`search` and `findall`):

```
[re.search(r'[^:]+', given_string).group()] + re.findall(r'(?<=[ (])\w+?(?=[,)])', given_string)

Output: ['constructor', 'some', 'parameters', 'here']
```